# Convert Mongodb query to Jasper Report query

Tags: mongodb, jasper-reports

Can you anyone help me in converting the following MongoDB query to Jasper Report supporting Mongo query

```
db.getCollection('Cases').find({"members":{$elemMatch :{memberID:"10001"}}})
```

I tried the following but its not giving any fields when I try to create Dataset

```
{
    'collectionName' : 'Cases',
    'findQuery' : {
        'members' : {'$elemMatch' :{'memberID':'$P{clientID}'}}
        },
    'findFields' : {'caseID':1,'_id':0}
}
```

`$P{clientID}` is the parameter I have created for the dataset. I placed the parameter without '' also. Still when I try to read the fields nothing shows up in the Dataset dialogue box. 
When I try the query by providing the value as follow

```
{
    'collectionName' : 'Cases',
    'findQuery' : {
        'members' : {'$elemMatch' :{'memberID':'10001'}}
        },
    'findFields' : {'caseID':1,'_id':0}
}
```

The `caseID` field is getting displayed

Comment: If the type of parameter is `String` try this: `'members' : {'$elemMatch' :{'memberID':$P{clientID}}}` or `'members' : {'$elemMatch' :{'memberID':'$P!{clientID}'}}`

Comment: I will try as you mentioned. I tried the following and it worked   {
 'collectionName' : 'Cases',
 'findQuery' : {
  'members' : {'$regex' : $P{clientID} }},
 'findFields' : {'caseID':1,'_id':0}
}